# Detect if a co-ordinate falls within a longitude and latitude boundary box

Tags: math, coordinates

Maths has never been my strong point and I'm struggling with a task.

I need to determine if a set of longitude and latitude co-ordinates fall inside a box, where the max/min longitude and max/min latitude have been given.

Any help would be appreciated.

** EDITED **

I'm using GPS co-ordinates, so the minimum longitude could be larger than the maximum longitude. i.e if the box is over date line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `minlat`, `maxlat`, `minlong` and `maxlong` (ie the 4 corners of your box) then it's a simple matter of determining whether your `lat` lies between `minlat` and `maxlat` and your `long` between `minlong` and `maxlong`.

If the box straddles `180°` either shift all your longitudes by adding (or subtracting) the same offset (take care with signs) or split the box into two along longitude `180°` and test both halves separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( latitude>= given.minimumLatitude and lat <= given.maximumLatitude )
{
    if( longitude >= given.minimumLongitude and longitude <= given.maximumLongitude )
    {
       return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
box = left, right, top, bottom

point = x, y

if (x >= left && x <= right && y >= bottom && y <= top) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```