# How to quickly determine which longitude & latitude range a point is in

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm

Suppose I have some (lng, lat) coordinate. I also have a big list of ranges,

[ { northeast: {lng, lat}, southwest: {lng, lat} } ... ]

How can I most effeciently determine which bucket the (lng, lat) point goes into?

Also, on a design perspective. Would it make more sense for the "list of ranges" to be on some database like mysql, monodb, or on something like memcached, redis?

Thank you.

Comment: Can buckets have common points?

Comment: They will not, guaranteed no

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832450/detect-if-a-co-ordinate-falls-within-a-longitude-and-latitude-boundary-box

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, that is not my question. That guy simply wanted to know if one point could match one box. I have a big list of boxes with 1 point and I want to know which box that one point goes into.

Comment: A quadtree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

You need to subdivide the list of ranges. You can look into a quadkey. It's similar to a quadtree. It uses a morton curve. You can very fast compute the quadkey of the range and the points. But you can also try a rectangle tree. You can also use an intervall tree.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL database might be a good answer.  If you imagine a table like `(bucketId, latNe, longNe, latSw, longSw)`, with indices on all the lat/long columns, then you could very efficiently get an answer by preparing and executing a query like `SELECT bucketId FROM bucketTable WHERE latNe > ? AND longNe < ? AND latSe < ? AND longSe > ?` using the desired lat/long coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

The [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtree) is an data structure designed for this kind of thing.  [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html) contains an implementation of it.  As does [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_searching/index.html).   Most modern [databases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/opengis-geometry-model.html) support this kind of thing natively as well.